# Why doesn't my script write content to the file?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I wrote a script in Python which once I execute it and press a button connected to a GPIO on my Raspberry Pi should:

- Print 'it works!'
- Create a file named 'it_works.txt' with the content 'yay!'

The script does print 'it works!' and creates the file, but the content is missing once I open it.
This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# SET GPIO Button-Pin
gpio = 9

# Main Function
def main():
  value = 0

  while True:

    if not GPIO.input(gpio):
      value += 0.01

    if value > 0:

     if GPIO.input(gpio):
       print "it works!"
       with open("it_works.txt", "w") as file:
           file.write("yay!")
           main()

     time.sleep(0.03)

  return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(gpio, GPIO.IN)
main()
```

I'm not experienced with Python, so I can't really say if I wrote something wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Indentation matters in Python. If you're going to post Python code, please make an effort to reproduce your indentation accurately. If readers have to try and guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems or introduce new ones into the program.

Comment: Why are you calling `main()` again inside the `with open(...)` block?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the current yìcode you provide, you set up correctly the pin of the GPIO and then your main enters in a loop where it continues to open a file in 'write' mode, but you never close it properly. Add the `file.close()` line after the  `with` declaration:

> with open("it_works.txt", "w") as file:
>
> ```
>     file.write("yay!")
>
>     main()
> ```
>
> file.close()

(CARE FOR INDENTATION)

Furthermore when you open a file in python with 'w' option it will truncate the content of the file. I don't know if this is relevant for you. I would suggest 'r+' or 'a'

Answer (score 0):

the file is never closed, the `with` statement opens the file for writing which is why you see it being created but before it being closed you call `main()` again during the course of which it is open again and again recursively.

i am not familiar with the workings of GPIO so i'm not sure about your use case but try to avoid doing the above

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were trying to call `main` inside the `with` statement again - a recursive call so to say.

Why do you call `main` again?

Also what you probably want to do is appending to the existing file - if the file exists. Here the mode "a" is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the RPi.GPIO package is, but I think you are using main function over and over in a wrong place, and it's recommended to close file after you wrote in it. use below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# SET GPIO Button-Pin
gpio = 9

# Main Function
def main():
  value = 0

  while True:

    if not GPIO.input(gpio):
      value += 0.01

    if value > 0:

     if GPIO.input(gpio):
       print "it works!"
       with open("it_works.txt", "w") as file:
           file.write("yay!")
           file.close()
     main()

     time.sleep(0.03)

  return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(gpio, GPIO.IN)
main()
```